# Incorrect Output While Comparing Two Lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, iteration

I'm trying to compare two lists to generate a buy/sell signals. The first list is a list of prices, while the second list is the simple moving average for those prices.

```
result = [590.0, 600.0, 590.0, 580.0, 570.0, 560.0, 570.0]
avrg = [580.0, 590.0, 593.33, 590.0, 580.0, 570.0, 566.67]
signal = ''

for prices in range(len(result)):
    for averages in range(len(avrg)):
        if result[prices] > avrg[averages]:
            signal = 'BUY'
        elif result[prices] < avrg[averages]:
            signal = 'SELL'
    lst.append(signal)
```

Output is

```
['BUY', 'BUY', 'BUY', 'BUY', 'BUY', 'SELL', 'BUY']
```

The output should be

```
['BUY', 'BUY', 'SELL', 'SELL', 'SELL', 'SELL', 'BUY']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = [590.0, 600.0, 590.0, 580.0, 570.0, 560.0, 570.0]
avrg = [580.0, 590.0, 593.33, 590.0, 580.0, 570.0, 566.67]
signal = []
for i in range(len(result)):
  if (result[i] > avrg[i]):
    signal.append('BUY')
  else:
    signal.append('SELL')
```

gives

```
>>> signal
['BUY', 'BUY', 'SELL', 'SELL', 'SELL', 'SELL', 'BUY']
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not looping over corresponding elements of `result` and `avrg`, you're looping over each combination.  For example, if you stick `print(result[prices], avrg[averages])` inside the loops, you see

```
590.0 580.0
590.0 590.0
590.0 593.33
590.0 590.0
590.0 580.0
590.0 570.0
590.0 566.67
600.0 580.0
600.0 590.0
600.0 593.33
[.. etc.]
```

So the `signal` that gets appended is really the result of comparing `result[prices]` with the *last* element of `avrg`.

I think what you really want to do is compare corresponding terms, and we can use `zip` for that.  Moreover, in Python we can loop over lists directly, and don't need to access them by index.  For example:

```
>>> list(zip(result, avrg))
[(590.0, 580.0), (600.0, 590.0), (590.0, 593.33), (580.0, 590.0), 
(570.0, 580.0), (560.0, 570.0), (570.0, 566.67)]
```

And so we could write

```
lst = []
for price, average in zip(result, avrg):
    if price > average:
        signal = 'BUY'
    else:
        signal = 'SELL'
    lst.append(signal)
```

(ignoring the `price == average` case for simplicity)

which produces

```
>>> lst
['BUY', 'BUY', 'SELL', 'SELL', 'SELL', 'SELL', 'BUY']
```

Here, we could even use a list comprehension instead of the loop:

```
>>> ['BUY' if price > average else 'SELL' for price, average in zip(result, avrg)]
['BUY', 'BUY', 'SELL', 'SELL', 'SELL', 'SELL', 'BUY']
```

but the more complex the logic is, the better off you are to simply write a clear for loop.

In any case, I think the basic problem is that you're doing a full all-prices-vs-all-average comparison and taking the last value when really you want to compare corresponding elements.

[PS: I just noticed something strange.  Isn't it the wrong way round to buy when the price is above average?  Shouldn't you buy when it's below average, and sell when it's above?]